# How can I add desktop notifications with WinUI 3?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, winui-3, winui

Does WinUI 3 have the feature to add desktop notifications?

See reference (see below)

[image: Desktop Notification]

Comment: Did you look into: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit and their toast notification?

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it and if there are any problems I will get in touch with you.

Answer (score 7):

Use build-in [AppNotification](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.windows.appnotifications.appnotification?view=windows-app-sdk-1.1) class:

```cs
// using Microsoft.Windows.AppNotifications;

public static bool SendNotificationToast(string title, string message)
{
    var xmlPayload = new string($@"
        <toast>    
            <visual>    
                <binding template=""ToastGeneric"">    
                    <text>{title}</text>
                    <text>{message}</text>    
                </binding>
            </visual>  
        </toast>");

    var toast = new AppNotification(xmlPayload);
    AppNotificationManager.Default.Show(toast);
    return toast.Id != 0;
}
```

---

Update 2023-03-12

Since *Windows App SDK 1.2* You can use [AppNotificationBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.windows.appnotifications.builder.appnotificationbuilder) class.

```cs
public static bool SendNotificationToast(string title, string message)
{
    var toast = new AppNotificationBuilder()
        .AddText(title)
        .AddText(message)
        .BuildNotification();

    AppNotificationManager.Default.Show(toast);
    return toast.Id != 0;
}
```

More advanced examples are available at [Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/windows-app-sdk/notifications/app-notifications/app-notifications-quickstart?tabs=cs#step-4-display-an-app-notification).

Answer (score 1):

1. Install the Nuget package:

   - Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.Notifications
2. Use 'ToastContentBuilder' to build the notification content.
3. Handling activation

   - After showing a notification, you will likely need to handle the user clicking the notification. Whether that means bringing up specific content after the user clicks it, opening your app in general, or performing an action when the user clicks the notification.

Reference:

[Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/shell/tiles-and-notifications/send-local-toast?tabs=uwp)